# Test of level of a student for secondary school

Tags: secondary-education, assessment, testing

I am looking for a test, paper based, execution time less than one hour, for an initial assessment of the math knowledge level of a secondary school student.

I need to evaluate, very approximately, if the real knowledge of the student is equivalent to the average of first year students or second year students, etc.

We are talking about very exceptional cases, individual students that comes to recovery courses with long records of problems in maths learning.

Comment: Do you mean for each year? Or for entry, or for end?

Comment: I need to evaluate, very approximately, if the real knowledge of the student is equivalent to the average of first year students or second one or ... .

Comment: I would say that it would depend on the country.  Different countries have different curricula for elementary (primary) school.  I suggest you indicate what country you are interested in.

Comment: Are you planning to give the test to just a few students or to very many?  Some standardized tests require the payment of fees and the permission of a third party.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: Country is Spain, however, it is not need a final results like "level 2º", this can be adapted. Neither is need in spanish, it could be translated, What is need is, by example, a test with increasing difficulty in concepts about rational numbers, or about equations, that gives an idea about the current situation.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: About the amount of tests, we are talking about very exceptional cases, individual students that comes to recovery courses with long records of problems in maths learning.

Comment: not sure if you are going to find this test already made for you. you can try google searching and crossing your fingers for luck. but this sounds like something you will need to make yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at Tailwind placement exams. They align with curriculua in the US so maybe this is not what you want. The enterprise involves a partnership with the University of Wisconsin System.

http://tailwindtesting.com/placementexams/math/

Comment: There were three links at the bottom.  Think  the math placement exam demo would be useful.